# Faster than memcmp

Tags: c++, optimization, g++

I have a UUID class that has an inbuilt 16 byte buffer for the UUID.

The `>`, `<`, `==`, `!=` overloaded operators just call `memcmp()` over the 16 byte value.

Since this class is going to be used on a 64-bit architecture only, would it be faster to compare the 128 bits using two 64-bit ints instead?

e.g.
Instead of:

```
memcmp(uuid1, uuid2, 16) == 0
```

Can I just do something like:

```
unsigned long* id1 = (unsigned long*)uuid1;
unsigned long* id2 = (unsigned long*)uuid2;
bool equal = (id1[0] == id2[0] && id1[1] == id2[1]);
```

Or does the `memcmp()` function used by G++ do this kind of optimisation already?
On the other hand, not using `memcmp()` will avoid the function call overhead yes?

Comment: possibly a premature optimisation?

Comment: Did you profile? After profiling, did you see that this was causing a significant bottleneck?

Comment: Try writing it both ways and see what's faster, but don't do this unless you need to.  Unless this is absolutely time-critical and you have verifiable proof that it's slowing down your program, this shouldn't make much a difference at all.

Comment: Where `id1[1]` and `id2[1]` points ... isn't it an out of range ?

Comment: g++ will probably inline the `memcmp` anyway, but check this bug: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43052 . In any case, as mentioned before, you should profile first.

Comment: Keep in mind that the actual number of bytes compared by `memcmp` nearly all the time is one (1) byte. It only does all the bytes in the (possibly rare) case that the two UUIDs are equal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With today's processors, there's a very good chance that the comparison is limited by the speed of fetching the bytes from memory. The comparison itself will likely be in parallel with it, whether it's byte by byte or 64-bit by 64-bit. The only way to be sure is to benchmark it.

As for the call overhead, it's quite possible that memcmp is implemented as an intrinsic function with no overhead at all. Check the generated assembly listing to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, turns out that it wasn't CPU bound at all even though I'm calling it millions of times.

Comment: Even an intrinsic has overhead, it must still *do* the comparison. In this case I'd suspect `int` comparison is slightly faster, since the memcmp is required to compare the bytes in order to determine the +/- return code.  Although if you compare to 0, and optmizer could reasonably just convert this to the `int` comparison since you don't actually care about the order.

Comment: A CMP instruction on modern CPUs is among the fastest operations out there (0.33 reciprocal throughput for r, r/i and 0.5 for m, r/i) - which is what memcmp will use anyways (why not?), so that's quite useless. Not that it'll matter as Mark correctly observes (even l2 cache is hundreds times slower than a cheap CMP)